# How to open MS-Word files under Genexus 15 and later versions

Tags: genexus

I have read WordDocument data type is [deprecated](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/wiki?2478,WordDocument%20Data%20Type) since GX15. Im close to migrate from Genexus X EV3 to Genexus 17/18 (Java generator), so how is the new way to handle docx files under Genexus 17/18 ? I can not find documentation about it.
Regards